# Does meteor provides Timepicker functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I am implenting time picker functionality. I had tried the jquery plugins for 
timepicker I got the error as "Jquery Undefined".

So I couldn't implement jquery plugin for timepicker.

So will you please suggest some way to implement timepicker using meteor.js?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you get the error "Jquery undefined" you are probably missing a reference to the jquery library. You should try adding a reference to it in your code and see if that helps.